# Using NavigationRail with multiple Futures

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a screen with NavigationRail where each destination displays table with different data fetched from backend.

I tried implementing it with NavigationRail and three futures, but each time I transit from one destination to another, I see a red screen with error on a second and then transit completes. My logs show following error:

The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building FutureBuilder<List>(state: _FutureBuilderState<List>#675cb):
Expected a value of type 'D1', but got one of type 'D2'

The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<List>

Could you please see if I am missing something? I tried the same approach with three futures with carousel_slider widget and did not run into a same problem. I guess I am misusing NavigationRail somehow.
Here is base code:

```
class DataScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DataScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<DataScreen> createState() => _DataScreenState();
}

class _DataScreenState extends State<DataScreen> {
  late Future<List<D1>> data1;
  late Future<List<D2>> data2;
  late Future<List<D3>> data3;

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    data1 = D1Service().getD1();
    data2 = D2Service().getD2();
    data3 = D3Service().getD3();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          NavigationRail(
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            groupAlignment: 0.0,
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
            labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
            leading: const SizedBox(),
            trailing: const SizedBox(),
            destinations: const <NavigationRailDestination>[
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: Text('D1'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.groups_outlined),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.groups),
                label: Text('D2'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.inventory_2_outlined),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.inventory_2),
                label: Text('D3'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
          const Spacer(),
          // This is the main content.
          Center(
            child: Container(
              child: _toTableAll(),
            ),
          ),
          const Spacer(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _toTableAll() {
    if (_selectedIndex == 0) {
      return _toTable(data1);
    } else if (_selectedIndex == 1) {
      return _toTable(data2);
    }
    return _toTable(data3);
  }

  Widget _toTable<T>(Future<List<T>> item) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<T>>(
      future: item,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 800),
            child: MTable(snapshot.data!),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        } else {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `snapshot.hasData` with `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done` solved the problem